# User logon with Apache Shiro and Sesame

Tags: apache, authentication, shiro, sesame

I have a Sesame triple store where I store users account and I'm building a Java Web Application with a login form.
I would like to use Apache Shiro to do this.

Does anyone know how to authenticate users using Shiro and Sesame?

Thank you.
-Antonio

Answer (score 1):

You will need a custom [Shiro Realm](http://shiro.apache.org/realm.html) to be able to use Sesame as the underlying database. Since Sesame does not currently provide such a Realm implementation, you will have to implement your own. I expect that you can do so by creating a Sesame-specific extension of [AuthenticatingRealm](http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/AuthenticatingRealm.html).